# How to implement Navigation component?

Tags: navigation, viewmodel, android-livedata

How do we start implementing navigation component in android ?

Didn't try yet just looking for the steps to start it.
I have worked for MVC and MVP as well but looking to explore view model like how it is different from previous patterns.